# Iteration through std::vector seems to be broken in only one function

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, stdvector

I have a vector of struct elements and in one function, when iterating through it, differente errors related to bound are thrown.

I am implementing an UDP Server-client connection where some messages must be acknowledged. I implement a vector of struct elements where each contains the message sent, and the time in milliseconds it was sent. I don't think this is really relevant, for I have tried the same function storing a std::string instead of the struct, but, just in case.

When I receive an ACK message, I iterate through this vector with no problem at all:

```
///WORKING CODE IN OTHER FUNCTIONS
auto it = mACKExpected.begin();
for (; it != mACKExpected.end(); it++)
{
    if (it->msg.msgCount() == count)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

However, I have a separate method connected to a QTimer timeout that checks if an acknowledgeable message sent more than a second ago has not been acknowledged yet:

```
///CODE 1
for (auto it = mACKExpected.begin();it!=mACKExpected.end();)
{
    if ((curTime - it->millis) > mquiMsgTimeout)
    {
        debug() << "Message" << it->msg.raw() << "(count: " << it->msg.msgCount() << ") not acknowledged.";
        send(QtStrMsg::newMsg(it->msg.msgType(), getCount(), it->msg.msgData()).raw());
    }
    ++it;
}
```

I have also tried by iterating as:

```
///CODE 2
for (auto it : mACKExpected)
{
    if ((curTime - it.millis) > mquiMsgTimeout)
    {
        debug() << "Message" << it.msg.raw() << "(count: " << it.msg.msgCount() << ") not acknowledged.";
        send(newMsg(it.msg.msgType(), getCount(), it.msg.msgData()).raw());
    }
}
```

Also by using const iterators, but there are always errors. In the ***CODE  1*** example, a "can't increment vector iterator past end" exception is thrown in the `++it;` line. 
In the last code, an std::bad_alloc{} instead, but in the `for(...` line. If I erase the current iterator by doing this:

```
if ((curTime - it->millis) > mquiMsgTimeout)
    {
        debug() << "Message" << it->msg.raw() << "(count: " << it->msg.msgCount() << ") not acknowledged.";
        send(QtStrMsg::newMsg(it->msg.msgType(), getCount(), it->msg.msgData()).raw());
        it=mACKExpected.erase(it);
    }
else
    ++it;
```

a "vector erase iterator outside range" error is risen in the erase line.

What can I do? I have been stuck with this for two days. I have tried using QVector instead, but the same problem occurs. It seems to me that something gets broken when calling this function, but I don't know what else to try. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide one [mcve] instead of several incomplete snippets

Comment: You change the vector somewhere, your loop iterators are invalidated.

Comment: "separate method connected to a QTimer timeout" this wouldn't run in a different thread, now, would it?

Comment: [Naming]: *"`for (auto it : mACKExpected)`"*. `it` is not an **iterator**, neutral `element`/`value` would be more appropriate (but even better use name with real meaning).

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Regarding the snippets, I know it's too long and non complete, but I intended to explain as good as I can my problem and the things I had tried.

Comment: @S.M. you are right, see comment to the first answer, it is related to it

Comment: @Jeffrey no, it all runs for sure in a single thread, in debug() I stamp the thread ID to be sure

Comment: It looks like you need use queue, not vector.

Comment: @S.M. the thing is that being UDP, I sometimes erase an element in the middle, so I think vector is more appropriate. If I am missing something, I would be glad to hear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If while you are iterating the vector changes contents, you are doomed.

```
send(newMsg(it.msg.msgType(), getCount(), it.msg.msgData()).raw());
```

this line probably causes, directly or indirectly, the vector to change contents.

Then the loop, all of which assume the vector is unchanged, errors out.  Luckily you have debug iterators that detect the problem.

There are a number of ways to fix the problem, but which one is correct depends on what you want to happen when the container changes content while iterating over it.  This is not a simple question to answer.

The easiest rule is to *never* leave the local control flow -- don't call callbacks -- while iterating over a container.

If callbacks are integral to your system, you now have to think of the semantics of removing or adding callbacks to your system.  I typically permit callbacks to be removed on-the-fly, but callbacks added during a callback sequence do not get fired.

In this semantics, your callback information would be a collection (vector) of shared_ptr or weak_ptr (depending on how unregistering works).  You'd copy this into a vector of weak_ptr.  Then you'd iterate over this vector.

For each element, you'd `.lock()` the ptr -- if it is null, you'd know that callback had been unregistered before you got around to calling it.  Then you'd invoke it.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Message>> mACKExpected;

std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Message>> lACKExpected( mACKExpected.begin(), mACKExpected.end() );

for (auto it : lACKExpected)
{
  auto ptr = it.lock();
  if (!ptr) continue;
  auto& e = *ptr;
  if ((curTime - e.millis) > mquiMsgTimeout)
  {
    debug() << "Message" << e.msg.raw() << "(count: " << e.msg.msgCount() << ") not acknowledged.";
    send(newMsg(e.msg.msgType(), getCount(), e.msg.msgData()).raw());
  }
}
```

now any modification to `mACKExpected` due to `send` doesn't mess with the loop.  And any element removed from `mACKExpected` has its `shared_ptr` reference count drop to 0, so the `lACKExpected` `weak_ptr` on `.lock()` returns a null `shared_ptr`, so the message is skipped.

Really, all of the code after `lACKExpected` is constructed should be in its own **non-member** function, so you don't accidentally read data from the class that might change in unexpected ways from callbacks.

This technique might be called "hardening your code to support reentrancy" loosely -- your class is reentrant, methods in the class can call out of the class, which can then result in calls back into the class.  By copying stuff out the the class, then using those copies to determine what callbacks to make, we make it harder for reentrancy to break the code.

Comment: It is late here (Spain) and I'll try sth based on this tomorrow. Exactly, the send function updates the vector by means of several Qt Slots invoked automatically, something I had not thought about. I just commented the send function and no more problems. I'll try tomorrow a different approach, for I need this to be implemented within a class method. Anyway, I am using a single thread, so as long as I ensure no callbacks are called within the loop I should have no problems, so maybe I use a temporary list or whatever to add the msgs, then in a separate for loop will send them. Thanks everyone.

Comment: As suggested by Yakk, it was the send function which indirectly caused the vector to grow. So far my working code looks like (will be optimized):
```
for (auto it = mACKExpected.begin(); it!=mACKExpected.end();++it)
 {
  if ((curTime - it->millis) > mquiMsgTimeout)
  {
   debug() << "Message" << it->msg.raw() << "(count: " << it->msg.msgCount() << ") not acknowledged.";
   acksToSend.push_back(QtStrMsg::newMsg(it->msg.msgType(), getCount(), it->msg.msgData()));
  }
 }```
Then I erase timed out elements (```vector::erase(std::remove_if...```) and send each acksToSend later on.
Tkanks